# UISLider change UILabel's value the right way

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, uislider

So I have this code to change the values of `UILabel` based on the value of `UISlider`:

```
- (void)slider03Changed:(UISlider *)slider{

    int value = 10;

    if (slider.value >= 0.1){
        value = 20;
    }
    if (slider.value >= 0.2){
        value = 30;
    }
    if (slider.value >= 0.3){
        value = 40;
    }
    if (slider.value >= 0.4){
        value = 50;
    }
    if (slider.value >= 0.5){
        value = 60;
    }
    if (slider.value >= 0.6){
        value = 70;
    }
    if (slider.value >= 0.7){
        value = 80;
    }
    if (slider.value >= 0.8){
        value = 90;
    }
    if (slider.value >= 0.9){
        value = 100;
    }

    lbl01.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u hours", value];
}
```

Everything works fine, but I'm worried about the quality of code here.

This code is quite, well, long. Is there any way to optimise it somehow? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use for loop :

```
- (void)slider03Changed:(UISlider *)slider{

    int value = 10;

    for (float i = 0.9; i > 0; i-=0.1)
    {
        if (slider.value >= i)
        {
           value = (i*100)+10; 
           break;
        }
    }

    lbl01.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u hours", value];
}
```

The formula used is:

```
(i*100)+10
```

For example:

```
(0.6*100)+10 = 70
(0.7*100)+10 = 80
and so on...
```

**UPDATE:**

You can optimize it further by start checking this case `slider.value >= 0.9` first.

Why ?

Because if it satisfy the case with higher value, then the rest of the your `if` statement will be useless. In the code I wrote, whenever the condition with most value of `slider.value` is satisfied, we  set the value of `value` variable and break out of the loop. This will prevent your code to  evaluate unnecessary cases.

For example:

Assume your `slider.value` = **0.95**

This is what will happen in your code:

```
(slider.value >= 0.1) ----> true ----> then ---> set value = 20
(slider.value >= 0.2) ----> true ----> then ---> set value = 30
(slider.value >= 0.3) ----> true ----> then ---> set value = 40
(slider.value >= 0.4) ----> true ----> then ---> set value = 50
(slider.value >= 0.5) ----> true ----> then ---> set value = 60
(slider.value >= 0.6) ----> true ----> then ---> set value = 70
(slider.value >= 0.7) ----> true ----> then ---> set value = 80
(slider.value >= 0.8) ----> true ----> then ---> set value = 90
(slider.value >= 0.9) ----> true ----> then ---> set value = 100
```

With my code:

```
(slider.value >= 0.9) ----> true ----> then ---> set value = 100 and break out of the loop
```

As you may see, with my code, it evaluates only 1 case.

Comment: Also, if you want to eliminate all those `if` and `for-loop`, @Anoop Vaidya's answer is a good solution (efficient as well).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need many `if`'s and you know only one is going to be executed, use `if-else ladder`.

In this case you can use as:(*this is not the best way*)

```
if (slider.value >= 0.9){
    value = 100;
}
else if (slider.value >= 0.8){
    value = 90;
}
else ....
```

---

Now to automate/making shorter code, this you can use as :

```
- (void)slider03Changed:(UISlider *)slider{
    lbl01.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f hours", round(value*10-.5)*10+10]);];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

once try like this i think here no need to use loop every time,

```
- (void)slider03Changed:(UISlider *)slider{

    float value = slider.value;

        int k=((int)(value*10)*10)+10;
        if(k==110){
            k=100;
        }
   lbl01.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours", value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, you might consider changing the UISlider so that the minimum and maximum values matched the output that you want -- i.e. min==0, max=99.  Those would be the minimumValue and maximumValue properties if you want to do it in code or the Minimum and Maximum fields in the Attributes Inspector if you're using Interface Builder.

Then the computation of the output value would be:

```
int value = slider.value;
    value = (value + 10) - value % 10;
```